# (Advanced?) Tufte-Like Layout for scientific/educational book

Tags: tufte, books, marginnote

I am writing a technical book and would like to employ a layout like the one used in "Principles Of Biochemistry", which IMHO is just beautiful. However, the Tufte-Book is not even close to what that book does, and I was wondering whether there exists already some secret template somewhere for me to use to achieve this... or do I have to re-invent the wheel maybe..?

I would like to have all those nice sidenotes/margin-notes as in the images attached, (colored boxed, images, and tables). Well, pretty much quite a very similar appearance i possible. Reading that book made me think that it must have been typeset with a Latex-like system.

Plese see attached images.
[image: TOC]
[image: A Page]
[image: A Page]

Comment: Maybe take a look here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends

Comment: "Reading that book made me think that it must have been typeset with a Latex-like system."... If you consider InDesign etc. LaTeX-like.

Comment: @Alexis I have seen this before positing this question. A very assortment of ideas but where it gets interesting no source available (as usual).

Comment: @TeXnician Right. My bad. I forgot to mention that I live by the mantra of sharing ideas and sharing software (or free as in OSS)... Besides, latex should be perfectly able to do such a design with just the source (if the one writing the TEX file knows how to do it; I am certainly gazillion light-years away from anything even close to the look-and-feel of the book I mentioned).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your question seems to broad. What exactly do you want? You should ask questions like `How do I add figures to ToC` or `How do I place figures in the margin`. Not `How can I make a document like this`.

Comment: Seems that could be written with LaTeX. Probably memoir class will be helpful. About colors and figures, thats up to you to specify it. And about a posible model document to follow, I suggest to look for a free physics book available in the web (http://www.lightandmatter.com) that its similar and have its source publicly available.

Comment: @djnavas Yes, LightAndMatter I found after reading more thoroughly the Stackexchange-Showcase thread (as nicely suggested by Alexis, thanks again for reminding me) following a link there to LM. The source is available on github, but it simply does not compile on my PC (Win10, MikTex using Texmaker as editor, Tied XeLatex and LuaLatex and everything, it complains that lm.cmd cannot be written to. Do I really have to mess with Mac or Linux for this to work?)

Comment: @Michael Fraiman I agree. Sorry. Call me lazy if you like, but I did not wan't to post a hundred questions yet, because I thought there might be someone who has a 'private' template or class not (yet?) introduced  into the general repository of latex (like miktex).  As it looks, I will have to start asking specific questions then.

Comment: @ Edward I don't remember well, but L&M is compiled with pdfLaTeX, I believe. Also, I have had problems with windows in this year blocking *.bat and *.cmd, that must be executed with elevated privileges (right click on the file and choose "... as administrator").